# Cannot access Google API using Refresh Token + OAuth 2 and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, razor, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get offline access to the Google API using OAuth 2.0 and after following Google's documentation closely I'm now unsure of what to do with the refresh token itself. I've tried using the access token gained from my refresh token POST request with my original code, but I now get a 403 Forbidden error.

Prior to this, I've been requesting a new access token every hour (manually) to gain access to the API and this has worked fine, but without using the refresh token in any way.

Once I've received my refresh token, is there any other data I need to send along with my new access token in my GET request to gain access? Do I still have to request a new access token every hour even if I have a refresh token?

Here's my code for sending GET requests which works fine with standard access tokens:

```
string access_token = "my_access_token";
string uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga1234567&max-results=50&access_token=" + access_token;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token;
request.Method = "GET"; 
var response = request.GetResponse();

var responseData = "";  

 HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
        Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
res.Close();
```